# R - Simple XML parse

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing

Let's say I ran code below :

```
url.df_1 = htmlTreeParse(url_1, useInternalNodes = T)
```

and got below htmlTree :

```
           <!-- ******************* related ******************* --> 
    <div class="more-related-box">

    <div id="app_related">
        <h3>Customers Also Bought</h3>
            <ul>
<li><a href="/app/ios/flick-golf/" title="Flick Golf!"><img src="http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/067/Purple/v4/25/a8/91/25a891df-fed4-9dc4-0d86-1c8f5acf893f/mzl.fcctkywr.75x75-65.jpg" class="app_icon"><span class="app_name">Flick Golf!</span><span class="category">Games</span></a></li>

              <li><a href="/app/ios/minecraft-pocket-edition/" title="Minecraft â€“ Pocket Edition"><img src="http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/070/Purple2/v4/3f/56/07/3f56074b-af27-8ba3-7ef8-c97314c13ee7/mzl.rfhcaysw.75x75-65.jpg" class="app_icon"><span class="app_name">Minecraft â€“ Pocket Edition</span><span class="category">Games</span></a></li>
```

What I want to grab from above is "flick-golf" and "minecraft-pocket-edition". (So the above is the part of htmltree and I want to grab these names and want to make them as a list or dataframe eventually.)

So far I tried this (and bunch of others)

```
getNodeSet(url.df_1, "//div[@id = 'app_related']//h3 ")
```

But I ended up getting

```
[[1]]
<h3>Customers Also Bought</h3> 

attr(,"class")
```

Any advice? Thank you!

Comment: You need to give us valid xml. The one posted is not valid.

Comment: Also question is unclear. Do you want to capture value of title attribute for node a? or something else?

Comment: Thanks- I edited my question. I would like to capture the title name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make sure your xml is well formed. I am assuming that you will take care of that. After that you just need right XPath arguement, which in your case will be `//li/a/@title`

```
> str <- '<div class="more-related-box">
+ <div id="app_related">
+ <h3>Customers Also Bought</h3>
+ <ul>
+ <li>
+ <a href="/app/ios/flick-golf/" title="Flick Golf!">
+ <img src="http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/067/Purple/v4/25/a8/91/25a891df-fed4-9dc4-0d86-1c8f5acf893f/mzl.fcctkywr.75x75-65.jpg" class="app_icon" />
+ <span class="app_name">Flick Golf!</span>
+ <span class="category">Games</span>
+ </a>
+ </li>
+ <li>
+ <a href="/app/ios/minecraft-pocket-edition/" title="Minecraft â€“ Pocket Edition">
+ <img src="http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/070/Purple2/v4/3f/56/07/3f56074b-af27-8ba3-7ef8-c97314c13ee7/mzl.rfhcaysw.75x75-65.jpg" class="app_icon" />
+ <span class="app_name">Minecraft â€“ Pocket Edition</span>
+ <span class="category">Games</span>
+ </a>
+ </li>
+ </ul>
+ </div>
+ </div>'
> doc <- xmlParse(str)
> getNodeSet(doc, "//li/a/@title")
[[1]]
        title 
"Flick Golf!" 
attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLAttributeValue"

[[2]]
                         title 
"Minecraft â€“ Pocket Edition" 
attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLAttributeValue"

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```